# VST2 interface dll entry points

Tags: c++, dll, plugins, mfc, vst

I am building a VST2 plugin. I want to know when to create a plugin window: on loading the dll (in my case in `InitInstance`), or some other point (maybe `AEffEditor::open`)?

I have subclassed `AEffEditor`. I am creating a window in `InitInstance` and showing and hiding the window in `AEffEditor::open` and `AEffEditor::close`.

It appears that `InitInstance` (dll load) is not a right point to create a window, but then when?

E.g. the host is creating 3 windows for 2 instances of insert (one on loading the dll).

Another question: when is `InitInstance` (dll load) called? At the host startup and at each send/insert?

Should I create a window per dll load (`m_pMainWnd`) or create them in separate threads and keep track of the windows? I.e. will the `m_pMainWnd` be different or will be same single window?

Comment: Solved by creating a window if not already existing, in `open()`.

Answer (score 0):

VST editor windows are supposed to be embedded in a host application window. That means you need a window reference (a HWND on Windows, a WindowRef on Mac with Carbon or an NSView on Mac with Cocoa if you use [Cockos extensions](http://www.reaper.fm/sdk/vst/vst_ext.php)) to that host window to be able to create your window.

VST API only passes that window reference when AEffEditor::open is called. And it becomes invalid when AEffEditor::close is called (even though the docs are not very specific about it). Thus, you need to create your window inside AEffEditor::open (as a child window of the window passed to you) and destroy it inside AEffEditor::close.

From this it follows that you need to create a separate window for each plugin *instance*. The user can put more than one instance of your plugin in different tracks and he/she expects that changes made to one of them don't affect the other.

Comment: If `open()` creates the window (and `close()` destroys it) then how can the window persist its data? I thought `open` and `close` are for showing and hiding the "existing" window, not for creating and destroying. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @user1288043 VST plugin window ("effect editor") reflects the current state of your plugin. Typically this state will be the VST parameters. You need to keep this data somewhere for saving, restoring, bank/preset switching anyway, maybe as member variables of your plugin object. Editor needs to be "dumb", any tweaking should update the parameters. And any parameter changes not caused by GUI tweaking (like automation or preset changes) need to be reflected. Like in the classic model/view pattern.